# The template parameter is not valid. The parameter value must be null

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-pipelines-yaml

I'm a beginner on Azure DevOps and I'm trying to create a CI pipeline for an simple ARM Template. So I have this file (test_template.json):

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccounts_dqed01dls_name": {
            "defaultValue": "dqed01als",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_dpm01_d_vnet_externalid": {
            "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx1234/resourceGroups/dpm01-vnets-d-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dpm01-d-vnet",
            "type": "String"
        },
        "Environment": {
            "value": "Acc",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
            "apiVersion": "2021-09-01",
            "name": "[parameters('storageAccounts_dqed01dls_name')]",
            "location": "westeurope",
            "tags": {
                "CBSPProduct": "Storage 4.0.1",
                "AppName": "DQEM",
                "Billing code": "XX000",
                "Business Application CI": "XX00546",
                "CIA": "001",
                "ContactMail": "user@contoso.comm",
                "ContactPhone": "+390000000",
                "Environment": "[parameters('Environment').value]",
                "Owner": "user@contoso.com",
                "Provider": "PTV_Azure"
                
(...)
```

And also this parameter file (test_parameters.json), which I have no idea why it exists because this parameters are also defined in the ARM template above

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "storageAccounts_dqed01dls_name": {
            "value": "dqed01dls"
        },
        "virtualNetworks_dpm01_d_vnet_externalid": {
            "value": "/subscriptions/xxx1234/resourceGroups/dpm01-vnets-d-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/"
        },
        "Environment": {
            "value": "Acc"
        }
    }
}
```

Then, I run this YAML pipeline:

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- "*"

parameters:
- name: Environment
  displayName: Environment
  type: string
  default: ubuntu-latest
  values:
  - Dev
  - Acc
  - Prod

stages:
  - stage: test
    jobs:
      - job: 'validateandtest'
        pool:
          vmimage: windows-latest
        steps:
        - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          inputs:
            deploymentScope: 'Resource Group'
            azureResourceManagerConnection: 'dpm01-devops-a-rg'
            subscriptionId: 'xxx1234'
            action: 'Create Or Update Resource Group'
            resourceGroupName: 'dpm01-devops-a-rg'
            location: 'West Europe'
            templateLocation: 'Linked artifact'
            csmFile: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/pipeline/test_template.json'
            deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

And I get this error:

```
##[error]Deployment template validation failed: 'The template parameter 'Environment' at line '1' and column '484' is not valid. The parameter value must be null. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-template/#parameters for usage details.'.
```

The idea was to pass Environment as a parameter to the ARM template. Since it didn't work, I hardcoded it, but get this error and I don't understand why it must be null.

Answer (score 1):

Look at line 14 of your ARM template:

```
        "Environment": {
------> "value": "Acc",
            "type": "string"
        }
```

Look at one of the other parameters:

```
        "virtualNetworks_dpm01_d_vnet_externalid": {
------> "defaultValue": "/subscriptions/xxx1234/resourceGroups/dpm01-vnets-d-rg/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/dpm01-d-vnet",
            "type": "String"
        },
```

You are specifying `value`, not `defaultValue`. I'm kind of surprised that's syntactically valid, but that's probably where the error is coming from: You are specifying a parameter value *in the template itself*.

Comment: Should the parameter be defined on a parameter file? But then how do I pass the parameter when running the YAML pipeline?

Comment: Look at your other parameters in the ARM template. They have a `defaultValue`. `Environment` doesn't. It has a `value`. Your parameters file should specify a `value`. Your ARM template's parameters section should specify a `defaultValue` (or no `defaultValue`, if it's a required parameter).

Answer (score 0):

There is no `value` attribute under `parameter`, according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/syntax#parameters). Make sure you provide `defaultValue` unless you want to have it set in CLI.
[image: Azure documentation]